# Display extra info upon clicking a row in a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I essentially have a table with rows and upon clicking a row, I would like a popUp box to appear. I have the div/HTML code for it. However, I am not sure how to implement the backend code of it.

1.) User clicks row
2.) It gets extra info from that row: For example, the row is only displaying $transactionID and $transactionAmount. Then the user clicks a row, a box pops up displaying the $transactionID, $transactionAmount, $transactionDate and $reference

How do I go about doing this? I am completely confused and have attempted to look everywhere to find a solution but can't seem to find any similar examples

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr[data-href]");
        rows.forEach(row => {
            row.addEventListener("click", () =>{
            // Not sure what to do here
            })
        })
    })
```

```css
.transfers table{
  width: 651px;
  margin: 450px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.transfers tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.transfers th{
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.transfers th, td{
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.transfers .id{
  text-align: left;
}

.transfers .amount{
  text-align: right;
}
td{width:217px;}
```

```html
<div class="transfers">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="id">ID</th>
                    <th class="amount">Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <?php
                /* $transactionList = displayTransfers($conn, $accountNumber); - This will display a row */
                foreach ($transactionList as $value){
                  $transactionID = $value['transactionID'];
                  $transactionAmount = $value['amount'];
                  $transactionDate = $value['transactionDate'];
                  $reference = $value['reference'];
                  
                  echo "<tr data-href='$value'>";
                        echo "<td style='background-color:$colour'>$transactionID</td>";
                        echo "<td class='amount' style='background-color:       $colour'>$transactionAmount</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**This was my approach but it doesn't work correctly: It won't actually update the values when clicked. Upon clicking a row, it will constantly display the same values from the first row of the table**

```js
function displayTransaction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("transactionBox");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```css
.transfers table{
  width: 651px;
  margin: 450px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.transfers tr{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

.transfers th{
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.transfers th, td{
  border: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.transfers .id{
  text-align: left;
}

.transfers .amount{
  text-align: right;
}
td{width:217px;}

#transactionBox{
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

transactionBox_class{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  opacity: 0;

}

.wrapper{
  margin: 150px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 15%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper h2{
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.wrapper .close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.wrapper .content{
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

form label{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.container p{
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="transfers">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="id">ID</th>
                    <th class="amount">Amount</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <?php
                /* $transactionList = displayTransfers($conn, $accountNumber); - This will display a row */
                foreach ($transactionList as $value){
                  $transactionID = $value['transactionID'];
                  $transactionAmount = $value['amount'];
                  $transactionDate = $value['transactionDate'];
                  $reference = $value['reference'];
                  
                  echo "<tr onclick='displayTransaction()'>";
                  echo "<td style='background-color:$colour'>$transactionID</td>";
                  echo "<td class='amount' style='background-color: $colour'>$transactionAmount</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                        echo "<div class='transactionBox_class' id='transactionBox'>
                                <div class='wrapper'>
                                    <h2>Transaction Details</h2>
                                        <div class='content'>
                                            <div class='container'>
                                                <form>         
                                                    <label>Transaction ID:</label>
                                                    <p>$transactionID</p>
                                                    <label>Amount:</label>
                                                    <p>$transactionAmount</p>
                                                    <label>Date:</label>
                                                    <p>$transactionDate</p>
                                                    <label>Reference:</label>
                                                    <p>$reference</p>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>";
                    }

                ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Either put everything in the DOM and hide the parts you don't want displaying, or make an AJAX request for the additional pieces.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class called visible or something and add it to the children in the  when it gets clicked.

You can use `element.classList.add("my-class");` to add a class (.remove("myclass") to remove it)

Comment: I have updated the post to attach my approach, is this something similar to what you are suggesting? If so, it works but it won't actually update the values when clicked. It will constantly display a box of the first row values

Comment: I don't really know php, but I'd expect your code to switch the display of the div inside the tr when you click the first tr. What are you trying to archieve exactly?

Comment: You are currently just getting one Element (The first one) with the id, you cound create a click listener on one object and in there change the child of that element. Thats what I expected to work...

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your `foreach` loop I can see that there are some rows of the table getting populated but the `id` remains the same for every transaction division that is `transactionBox` which is why you are getting only first row which is the first element with the `id`.

**Solutions :-**

1. Create a dynamic ID for each of the row's transaction division.

```
echo "<tr onclick='displayTransaction(".$transactionID.")'>";
echo "<td style='background-color:$colour'>$transactionID</td>";
echo "<td class='amount' style='background-color: $colour'>$transactionAmount</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                        echo "<div class='transactionBox_class' id='transactionBox_".$transactionID."'>
                                <div class='wrapper'>
                                    <h2>Transaction Details</h2>
```

2. Use custom attribute but yaah unique.

```
echo "<tr onclick='displayTransaction(this)' transation='".$transactionID."'>";
                  echo "<td style='background-color:$colour'>$transactionID</td>";
                  echo "<td class='amount' style='background-color: $colour'>$transactionAmount</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                        echo "<div class='transactionBox_class' id='transactionBox' transaction-type='".$transactionID"'>
                                <div class='wrapper'>
                                    <h2>Transaction Details</h2>
```

The working examples are below.

```js
function showDetails_1(elem){
  var actual_elem = "#transaction_"+elem;
  console.log(actual_elem)
  $(actual_elem).attr("style","display:block");
}

function showDetails_2(elem){
  var actual_elem = "[transaction-type="+$(elem).attr("transaction")+"]";
  console.log(actual_elem);
  $(actual_elem).attr("style","display:block");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=3>
<tr>
<th>column 1</th>
<th>column 2</th>
<th>column 3</th>
<th>column 4</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>data 1</td>
<td>data 2</td>
<td>data 3</td>
<td><button onclick="showDetails_1(433)">show</button></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<div class="tansaction" style="display:none" id="transaction_433">
Yo..! here are the details_1
</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>data 1</td>
<td>data 2</td>
<td>data 3</td>
<td><button onclick="showDetails_2(this)" transaction="433">show</button></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">
<div class="tansaction" style="display:none" id="transaction" transaction-type="433">
Yo..! here are the details_2
</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```